# Importing an xmlfile into an existing excel sheet via VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I have a rather large xml-file which I want to import into an existing excelfile, into a specific sheet. My own code is rather sluggish. I have tried using the openXml method, but this produces an non-usable output

The code I have tried (and works, but it's really slow) is listed here. The XML-file contains around 10000 items with for each item has a 22 other values which I need. If I run this code, excel takes about 2 or 3 minutes to put all the data in the sheet, which is not really acceptable.

The file itself is a bit poorly formatted, with two separate xml-lists into one xml-file. I have no control over this sadly enough.

I have also tried to use the workbook.openXML-option, but this stumbles over the two different xmlstructures which are in the sourcefile, making it pretty unusable for me unless i spend more time cleaning that table up, but that's not a really tidy solution.

(I have not posted the XML here, since it's company data).

```
XDoc.Load (strPath)

Set inputXML = XDoc.SelectNodes("//<nodes_i_need>")

xmllengte = Int(inputXML.Length)
ReDim listinputXML(xmllengte, 22)
xmlTeller = 0

For Each element In inputXML:
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 0) = element.ChildNodes(0).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 1) = element.ChildNodes(1).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 2) = element.ChildNodes(2).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 3) = element.ChildNodes(3).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 4) = element.ChildNodes(4).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 5) = element.ChildNodes(5).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 6) = element.ChildNodes(6).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 7) = element.ChildNodes(7).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 8) = element.ChildNodes(8).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 9) = element.ChildNodes(9).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 10) = element.ChildNodes(10).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 11) = element.ChildNodes(11).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 12) = element.ChildNodes(12).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 13) = element.ChildNodes(13).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 14) = element.ChildNodes(14).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 15) = element.ChildNodes(15).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 16) = element.ChildNodes(16).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 17) = element.ChildNodes(17).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 18) = element.ChildNodes(18).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 19) = element.ChildNodes(19).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 20) = element.ChildNodes(20).Text
    listinputXML(xmlTeller, 21) = element.ChildNodes(21).Text

    xmlTeller = xmlTeller + 1
Next element

Sheets("testing").Range("A2", CStr("V" & inputXML.Length)) = listinputXML
```

Comment: Can't you try to split the XML into two (temporary) files and use the `workbook.openXML` with these two files?

Comment: I have thought about that, but not really an option. This sheet will be used by another person, and the whole idea is to cut out manual labour. The split kinda would make it more troublesome

Comment: Why - you could do this with VBA. Assuming that it's not hard to identify the end of the first and start of the second list, it's only a few lines of code.

Comment: This approach looks ok. Have you profiled the code to know where it is slow? How big is your XML file you are reading in?

Comment: Please post sample of XML (since it is large, post the root and several nodes, enough to know the repeating pattern) and the desired result (i.e., how tabular output should render).

Comment: the file is an output from an HR system which can range from a 5 to 20MB :) Anyhow I was pretty blind focused on coding, but found a better fix: just put the XML into a sheet via excel itself. It creates a persistent connection, which you can adjust to auto update whenever the file is opened. Seems I was trying to overengineer it bigtime where there was an easy solution right in front of me.